# Build HTML5 audio player with web audio API

Tags: html, web-audio-api

The `<audio>` tag streams the input and plays it. This is not suitable when we have to sync multiple audios. Explained here in SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498601/287100

So I would like to build an audio player which doesn't stream audio rather it downloads it or uses web audio API. I know how to load audio using API but don't know how to hook up it with progress bar with seeking feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a (very bare-bones and not particularly nice) little player I just made on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/lenapigo/1/edit

There have been a lot of questions on StackOverflow about making simple players, so hopefully this will be a good enough example that it can be helpful to people.

I didn't take the time to really comment this, but I think the code is reasonably clean and variables have fairly descriptive names, so hopefully that'll be enough to provide some value.

Let me know if you have any questions. But I probably won't be able to dedicate much time to actually writing any additional code for this if you want more features.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin!! This is what I was looking for. I should be able to customize it according to my need. I will let you know if I have any questions.